no main manifest attribute, in original-MCP-1.8.9.jar
I made a minecraft client with maven and when I try mvn clean package, it works but when I'm running it I get this: no main manifest attribute, in original-MCP-1.8.9.jar and I have tried to find out what to do but I can't so but here is the manifest:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.3.0

And my pom.xml is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.marcloud.mcp.189</groupId>
    <artifactId>MCP</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.9</version>
    <description>MCP for 1.8.9</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

There are more but that just repository
I tried to change mainclass but don't know what to change it to and I'm expecting to use the .jar to play minecraft with my client

It looks like your Manifest is missing the Main-Class entry. You should be able to configure maven-jar-plugin to add one - see "Make the Jar Executable" - https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html
